# try statement musr have at least one except or finally

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi everyone I have an error code on my code.
try statement must have at least one except or finally clause pylane and ,
except expression  pylance.

this is my code

```
def get_move(self, game):
    valid_square = False
    val = None
    while not valid_square:
        square = input(self.letter +'\'s turn. Input move (0-9): ' )
    try:
            val = int(square) 
    if val not in game.available_moves() : 
            raise ValueError
            valid_square = True 
    except ValueError:
    print('invalid square. ')
    
    return val
```

I tried to change the kidney instruction blocks to make the same mistake again.
i tried I rewrote my code and I still get the same resultt

Comment: The indentation of `print('invalid square. ')` is off. In fact, it's off in several places.

Comment: You have an `if` where there should be the `except`

Comment: SORRY I FIX my mistake

Answer (score -1):

i think the if block may have to under the try block:

```
def get_move(self, game):
    valid_square = False
    val = None
    while not valid_square:
        square = input(self.letter + '\'s turn. Input move (0-9): ')
        try:
            val = int(square)
            // put the if block under the try block.
            if val not in game.available_moves():
                raise ValueError
            valid_square = True
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid square. Please enter a valid move (0-9).')

    return val
```

please check the indentation also. This way, you will get rid of the problem. I am happy to look forward on this.